# Implementing a neural network to play a game in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network

I am a student looking to code an artificial intelligence project in Python 3. I want to create a feed-forward neural network that can learn to play a game. I have read up about how neural networks work, about the training procedure etc, so I am fairly confident I can code the network. Coding the game is also manageable.

The thing I can't find anywhere is *how they interlink* and how to make the game run smoothly.

For instance, suppose the main structure of the code looks something like this:

```
while True:
    gameUpdate()
    networkUpdate() #Recalculates outputs based on current game state
```

Would the network update quick enough to allow a passable game frame rate?

If the structure was different to this, what would it look like and how would it function?

Answer (score 0):

> Would the network update quick enough to allow a passable game frame rate?

Short answer: probably not - refitting the weights of a network takes a while, even for simple problems.

The good news is, you can probably re-frame the problem, depending on what you expect from the network.

You could have a network that takes features from the environment in the game as input, and produces output for what to do next (a key stroke, a direction, something to say, a stock to buy, etc.). You then run an "epoch" or "generation" of the game, and then create a measure for how well the network did (a score, total profit, etc.). You then use that score to compute a cost function (how far away are you from the desired outcome), which you can then use to refit the weights in the network.

Thus, the workflow is:

1. Let the network play the game (neural nets are generally pretty fast at taking input from their environment and generating predictions/output).
2. Refit the network based upon how well it performed.
3. Repeat for n iterations until your network is MLG

Other readers please comment whether I've approached this appropriately, because I'm interested in what the accepted general approach would be. I've never done a project like this but I imagine this is how it would go down.